# mysql merge query in one output with different fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have four db table,

**tableA, tableB, tableC, tableD**

I am listing records with join. These all working fine.
My query is like following.

```
Select DISTINCT A.*, B.loginname, B.email, C.full_name, C.address1, C.state, C.city, D.*
FROM ( 
tableA AS A 
INNER JOIN tableB AS B ON B.user_id = A.id
INNER JOIN tableC AS C ON C.user_id = A.id 
INNER JOIN tableD AS D ON D.user_id = A.id 
) WHERE A.id = '269' ORDER BY A.created_date DESC
```

Now, issue is i have created four another table with almost same details but there are different fields and columns. So i can not use **UNION**.

**tableE, tableF, tableG, tableH**

i want to merge output to display. And output should be ORDER BY A.created_date OR ORDER BY E.created_date

Advanced thanks...

Comment: So what is the problem? Join these table also.

Comment: Hi Ankit,
There is no relation between tableA-D and table-E-H

Comment: Can you please share the structure of newly created tables.

Comment: You should provide sample data and and example of the desired outcome.

Comment: If you have relation between tableA-D and tableE-H than use JOIN, otherwise how you gonna join them? (like join candies with elephants, only way - random)

Comment: There is relation between GROUP-A(tableA to tableD), but there is no relation between GROUP-A to GROUP-B(tableE to tableH)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` (or `UNION`, if you want duplicates removed) between two tables with differently named columns by declaring name aliases.

```
       SELECT 'first' AS source, a,b,c,d
         FROM first
     UNION ALL
       SELECT 'second' AS source, q AS a, r AS b, s AS c, t AS d
         FROM second
```

This will yield a result set (virtual table) with columns named source,a,b,c,d.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am not getting your example. can you plz be clear with my above query?